# How to match and get non-matching records in cross sheets?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, importrange

I have a Google sheet, my client also has another Google sheet. so I want to get entires from my client's sheet (Column B) which one does not match with my sheet (column B). How can I match and get non-matching values from my client's sheet to my sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get values from client's sheet, first run this formula:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("client-sheet-ID", "sheetname!B2:B")
```

then you can try:

```
=FILTER(IMPORTRANGE("client-sheet-ID", "sheetname!B2:B"), 
 NOT(REGEXMATCH(IMPORTRANGE("client-sheet-ID", "sheetname!B2:B"), 
 "^"&TEXTJOIN("$|^", 1, UNIQUE(B2:B))&"$")))
```

Comment: Thanks for help, Just one question as I have a lot of data so its make speed slow, can I use a filter in this formula, I mean if my sheet column C have done value then formula don't chk that values or you can say if column c empty the formula get non match entires. I already have entries so we don't need to fetch entries first from client sheet, hope you got my point, thanks again for this wonderful help

Comment: One thing more like my client has an entry like big box 6 but in my sheet only big box 5 entry formula not showing this mismatch entry in the column where I paste formula

Comment: not sure if I get you but try: `=FILTER(IMPORTRANGE("client-sheet-ID", "sheetname!B2:B"), 
 NOT(REGEXMATCH(IMPORTRANGE("client-sheet-ID", "sheetname!B2:B"), 
 "^"&TEXTJOIN("$|^", 1, UNIQUE(FILTER(B2:B, C2:C<>"")))&"$")))`

Comment: Thanks, still one issue hope you don't mind, my and my clients entires have some difference like in my entry its notebook 1 and in my client sheet book its note book 1. so their many differences like upper case lower case some extra words in starting or in end but they are same entries so is their way to filter search with these conditions I mean consider upper and lower case values same , and also space and non space consider same or consider value match if text match 60% like we make any condition if text match 60% formula consider match, hope you got it. Thanks Again for your time.

Comment: for upper/lower case: `=ARRAYFORMULA(FILTER(IMPORTRANGE("client-sheet-ID", "sheetname!B2:B"), NOT(REGEXMATCH(LOWER(IMPORTRANGE("client-sheet-ID", "sheetname!B2:B")), "^"&LOWER(TEXTJOIN("$|^", 1, UNIQUE(FILTER(B2:B, C2:C<>""))))&"$"))))`

Comment: and for space/non-space fix: `=ARRAYFORMULA(FILTER(IMPORTRANGE("client-sheet-ID", "sheetname!B2:B"), NOT(REGEXMATCH(LOWER(SUBSTITUTE(IMPORTRANGE("client-sheet-ID", "sheetname!B2:B"), " ", )), "^"&LOWER(TEXTJOIN("$|^", 1, UNIQUE(SUBSTITUTE(FILTER(B2:B, C2:C<>""), " ", ))))&"$"))))`